# How can you read commands from another file using Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, discord.js

So. I've been searching for a while, and couldn't seem to find anything that particularly applies. So far, I've got this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

Then, in my second file, located in commands, which is named *ping.js*

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'Ping!',
    cooldown: 5,
    execute(message) {
        message.channel.send('Pong.');
    },
};
```

The error that I've been getting is the following,

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './commands/hello.js'
Require stack:
- /Users/SurajAnand/Desktop/Discord/discordBot/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:976:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:859:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/SurajAnand/Desktop/Discord/discordBot/index.js:11:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/Users/SurajAnand/Desktop/Discord/discordBot/index.js' ]
}
```

[image: gest]

I've just started to get into JS for the sake of making a fun little bot to mess with some friends. I tried to run this piece of code off of the discord.js guide, and it seems incredibly cool... Just that I can't seem to get it to work, so any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your directory structure? (https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.dAdS8zNnE7STmdGYhIPWXgHaKe%26pid%3DApi&f=1)

Comment: Not sure how to make it look exactly like that in StackOverFlow, but I sent a screen shot of how it looks in Visual Studio Code. Hope that works for what you were asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it looks like just the relative path is wrong.

If you call `./commands/hello.js` in `index.js`, it will look in `discordBot/commands/hello.js`, which obviously doesn't exist. Change it from `./commands/hello.js` to `../commands/hello.js`, this should work.

Another option would be moving the `commands` folder into `discordBot`,which may be a bit cleaner but that is up to you to decide

Comment: Just wanted to make sure, since it's seeming to be giving me an error. Would moving the commands folder into the discordBot folder and leaving:

 `./const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));` 

like that what you're saying, because it's telling me there's no file / directory when I move it in. How would I have to write that line?

Comment: If you move the folder, you can leave the relative path with `./`. However is it international, that you write `./const`? That one seems a bit weird, the rest looks right tho. Perhaps you need to restart your bot and/or IDE.